# FirebaseDB values in MIT App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor

How to set variables to Firebase DB values in MIT App Inventor?

I tried with direct setting but the blocks cant match.

Answer (score 0):

Because getting values from an online database like firebase is asynchronous (it can take a second to complete), you have to ask for the values you want and wait for the database to give them to you. See the screenshot below for an example.

It would also help if you could please edit your question to provide some more information. You could include a screenshot of your relevant blocks or describe the problem more thoroughly.

[image: Block code]